# MySQL LIKE clause with numbers fails because of PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm experiencing unexpected results from a query when using numbers as pattern.
The query looks like this:

```
SELECT Code FROM table WHERE Code LIKE '%xxx%'
```

Everything is fine when xxx are letters, but when they are numbers the query returned by the remote PHP is wrong.
It seems as if the starting %nn is interpreted as an ASCII code.

Example:

```
SELECT Code FROM table WHERE Code LIKE '%26F%'
```

is returned as: 
SELECT Code FROM table WHERE Code LIKE '&F%'

Javascript code sample:

```
find = "26F";
srch = "Code LIKE '%" + find + "%'";
url: "load_searched_record.php?target="+srch;
...
```

PHP simplified code:

```
$target = $_GET['target'];
echo $target;
```

Since I removed all the MySql code for testing, leaving only the above 2 rows, it is quite evident that the problem in originated from PHP, but why?
Should I encode in same way the query? If yes, how?
Thanks

Pls note that the PHP file is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: You probably need to encode your srch parameter in your url.  The %## is being interpreted as a hex code for a character in the url

Comment: `%26` Corresponds to an ampersand when used in an url...

Comment: https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/

Comment: It seems like you use unvalidated user input as part of a MySQL query. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That’s because you failed to URL-encode the values you are putting into the query string properly … (and that is not PHP’s fault.)

You need to use `encodeURIComponent` on the value, before you append it to the URL:

`"load_searched_record.php?target="+encodeURIComponent(srch)`